# I cannot install xampp on windows server 2012 r2

Tags: windows, server, xampp

I cannot install xampp correctly, when I start I get the message:

```
Initializing Control Panel
Windows Version: Windows Server 2012 R2  64-bit
XAMPP Version: 7.4.2
Control Panel Version: 3.2.4  [ Compiled: Jun 5th 2019 ]
Running with Administrator rights - good!
XAMPP Installation Directory: "d:\xampp\"
Checking for prerequisites
Required XAMPP prerequisite not found!
You do not appear to have the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Runtimes installed
This is required for XAMPP to fully function
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5582
Initializing Modules
The FileZilla module is disabled
The Mercury module is disabled
Starting Check-Timer
Control Panel Ready
```

The problem is here, probably, finding the correct matches between the xampp version, the operating system (which I cannot change) and the Microsoft Visual C++ version. Please help!

Serban

Comment: "You do not appear to have the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Runtimes installed" - The message is straightforward. Are you unable to install the runtimes on your Windows server? The suggested link is dead, sure, but perhaps you could try your luck with archive.org

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In my Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features I see Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Runtimes, this is the point